# When testing for a thrown exception, how much about that exception should I test?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, exception

This falls in line with my shallow understanding of Exception handling best practices.

If I'm writing unit tests for test cases that throw exceptions, do I only care that the correct exception *type* was thrown, or should I be checking more? Specifically:

1. If I call a method and expect a NullReferenceException, should I inspect that exception and make sure it came from where I'm expecting it to come from?
2. If an exception is thrown, should I immediately not care about state anymore, or is it still valid to make assertions about the state of the system?
3. If I pass nulls into a method, and a NullArgumentException is thrown, do I care for which argument it is thrown, or only that it was thrown?

I'm currently of the opinion that once an exception is thrown, all bets are off in terms of system state, and digging deep into exceptions is bad since at that point you're starting to inspect how your method is implemented.

thanks,
Mark

Comment: Seems to me that it all depends on the use case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I'm writing unit tests for test cases that throw exceptions, do I only care that the correct exception type was thrown, or should I be checking more?

If you treat test as something that drives your application design - that you need to check everything that makes sense for further class client.

> If I call a method and expect a NullReferenceException, should I inspect that exception and make sure it came from where I'm expecting it to come from?

In tests you always check if on known impact you get the desired results. So you call the method, and catch the exception. You shouldn't care of what and how had thrown it - you're just fine with the fact it had been thrown.

> If an exception is thrown, should I immediately not care about state anymore, or is it still valid to make assertions about the state of the system?

It depends on the requirements. If your app/library should be able to work after exception handling and has the valid state - you need to check that.

> If I pass nulls into a method, and a NullArgumentException is thrown, do I care for which argument it is thrown, or only that it was thrown?

Assume your library as a black box. You pass something there, you retrieve something back. Doesn't matter how the results has been produced. Does matter what has been produced.

**UPD**:

as @eschneider mentioned in the comments - you should also check that the exception thrown is of a correct type.

Comment: You probably should make sure you throw the correct type of exception, as a consumer may want to catch that specific exception type. Also if it's a custom exception that you follow MS design rules.

Comment: Yep, I didn't state it explicitly because I thought it is obvious

Answer (score 1):

> *If I call a method and expect a NullReferenceException, should I inspect that exception and make sure it came from where I'm expecting it to come from?*

Is the knowledge about your code you gain from that test important? If it is - test for it. With NRE it might be enough (and usually is) that you *know it was thrown under certain conditions*, and that's all about it.

> *If an exception is thrown, should I immediately not care about state anymore, or is it still valid to make assertions about the state of the system?*

That's totally up to your requirements. If state after exceptional situation needs to be *handled* in some ways, then you definitely should write tests for that.

> *If I pass nulls into a method, and a NullArgumentException is thrown, do I care for which argument it is thrown, or only that it was thrown?*

Think about your end user. Will he care what argument caused the exception? Will you care? If your end user will be programmer going through log file to search for possible cause of failure, then I can imagine he'll be thankful you provided that information. It's always the question of *"Is it of any value for the user?"*. If it is (and you want to assure that value has been provided) - test for it.

> *I'm currently of the opinion that once an exception is thrown, all bets are off in terms of system state, and digging deep into exceptions is bad since at that point you're starting to inspect how your method is implemented.*

Exception as the name would indicate means *exceptional situation*. Whether all bets are off, depends **only** on what's your application take on those exceptional situations. If all bets are off, I assume your application would act the same (handling it in the most simple way and forgetting about it). However, if your code wants to *do something* (like log, format for end user, rethrow, etc.) with said exception, then verifying it indeed is the correct exception, with proper message, thrown at some well-defined point - all those gain value and are worth testing for.